# Lodash JS - Simulate '_.intersectionWith' in plain vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to write an equivalent simple Javascript method for '_.intersectionWith' method of LodashJs library

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.intersectionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);

Output: [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }]
```

I wanted it work on array of strings as well. Is there any way to do it without O(n^2) iterations ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: [The source is available on GitHub...](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L7020)

Comment: Yes. But I wanted a single simple plain Javascript function. Lodash code has too many dependent internal methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a highly functional, plain-JS implementation of [`_.intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#intersectionWith):

```js
var objects = [{'x':1,'y':2},{'x':2,'y':1}],
    others = [{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':1,'y':2}];

function isEqual(a, b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}

function intersectionWith(firstArray) {
  var otherArrays = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1),
      comparator = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  return firstArray.filter(function(a) {
    return otherArrays.every(function(arr) {
      return arr.some(function(b) {
        return comparator(a, b);
      });
    });
  });
}

console.log(intersectionWith(objects, others, isEqual));
```

In ES6, this can be even shorter if you allow the comparator to be the first parameter.

```
function intersectionWith() {
  var [comp, first, ...others] = [...arguments];
  return first.filter(a => others.every(arr => arr.some(b => comp(a, b))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UnderscoreJS 's annotated source has a rather vanilla implementation for intersection:

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-62

```
  _.intersection = function(array) {
    var result = [];
    var argsLength = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0, length = getLength(array); i < length; i++) {
      var item = array[i];
      if (_.contains(result, item)) continue;
      for (var j = 1; j < argsLength; j++) {
        if (!_.contains(arguments[j], item)) break;
      }
      if (j === argsLength) result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
  };
```

The only dependencies, `_.contains` and `getLength` are pretty trivial as well.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.